# Replacing Server Header in Tomcat with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to automatically replace the server header in Apache Tomcat to prevent telling people I am using Apache. I'm currently using sed to try to accomplish this. I am running the below command:

sed -ir 's/(?<=server=")(.*)(?=")/IAmATeaPot/g' ./checktext.xml

I am trying change the checktext.xml in the same directory I am running the command which currently reads

Connector port="8080" ...
            server="Apache" />

and change it to:

Connector port="8080" ...
            server="IAmATeaPot" />

My regex appropriately captures the string within the quotes and works in regex checkers online, however nothing happens and I get no error. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Online regex checkers are practically useless, as you've just found out, since every command line tool uses it's own specific combinations of regexp standards+extensions+delimiters+arguments. So you can't reliably check a regexp in some online tool and expect it to work in any command line tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do a much cleaner job without having to deal with lookaheads and lookbehinds.

`s/server="[^"]*"/server="IAmATeapot"/`

You're looking for `server="` and then 0 or more non-`"` characters, and then a closing `"`, and then replacing the entire thing with `server="IAmATeapot"`.